# Protocol Buffers Java set optional message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm having problem with understanding how to use Protocol Buffers in Java.
My `client.proto` file:

```
message MyMessage {
        required int32 tag = 1;
        extensions 100 to max;
}

extend MyMessage {
        optional Hello hello = 100;
        optional Login login = 101;
}

message Hello {
        required uint32 version = 1;
}

message Login {
        required string username = 1;
        required string password = 2;
}
```

I would like to send `MyMessage` with `Hello`. I can create `MyMessage` or `Hello` object using builders but how to add `Hello` to `MyMessage`? I tried like below but I get an exception:

```
    Client.MyMessage.Builder mm = Client.MyMessage.newBuilder();
    mm.setTag(100);
    Client.Hello hello = Client.Hello.newBuilder().setVersion(1).build();
    u.setExtension(Client.hello, h);     // exception here
    Client.MyMessage message = mm.build();
```

Exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse protocol buffer descriptor for generated code.
    at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Descriptors.java:311)
    at com.test2.Client.<clinit>(Client.java:4153)
    at com.test2.MainActivity$Net.send(MainActivity.java:383)
```